# Angular, Firebase deleteUser() not deleting anonymous users in prod, works in dev project

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

running into a weird situation with a Firebase function. I am trying to cleanup anonymous users and I have used the code below

```
// Delete all Anonymous Users
export const cleanupUsers = functions.pubsub.schedule('01 00 * * *')
.timeZone('America/Los_Angeles') // Users can choose timezone - default is America/Los_Angeles
.onRun(async context => {
  //Get the list of all Users
  const allUsers = await admin.auth().listUsers();
  allUsers.users.forEach(async(user) => {
    console.log('This USER has been read: ', user.email, user.providerData.length);
    if (user.providerData.length === 0) {
      console.log('This USER will now be deleted: ', user.email, user.uid);
      await admin.auth().deleteUser(user.uid).then(res => {
        console.log('This USER has been deleted: ', res);
      }).catch(err => console.log('Error on delete of user', err));
    }
  });
});
```

Strange thing is that it works on my "dev" project in Firebase, but when I deploy the same function to my prod project it does not delete the anonymous users. I don't get an error, it just doesn't do the delete user part. Here is part of the log:

```
1:05:11.793 PM cleanup-cleanupUsers
This USER has been read:  undefined 0 
1:05:11.793 PM cleanup-cleanupUsers
This USER will now be deleted: undefined b79lTv0ckeR67IlNXSnNEGr0ZfD2
1:05:11.891 PM cleanup-cleanupUsers
Function execution took 1004 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
```

As you can see by the log, it does read the anonymous user, it knows the uid, but for some reason, in prod only, it doesn't delete the user.

Any ideas as to why it doesn't do the delete?

Comment: My first step to troubleshoot is always to run the same command in a local Node.js script. So if you run `admin.auth().deleteUser("b79lTv0ckeR67IlNXSnNEGr0ZfD2")` locally, does it delete the user?

Comment: I've never run a Firebase function locally, how do you even do that? Any Idea why it works in my DEV project. That would indicate the actual code works, maybe? An auth issue?

Comment: You should be able to just run the Node.js code in a local script, without anything related to Cloud Functions. That will actually help you isolate the problem: if it works locally, it is related to Cloud Functions. If you get the same problem locally, you've rules out Cloud Functions as a cause.